# Is there any maximum reqest() call limit per second in electron js?

Tags: npm, electron

I am using request() in a for loop to post data to a server. Will it fail to post all data. Is there any limit of data posting rate in electron js. Here, request() mathod is of **request** npm module.

```
const request = require('request);
sendData(reqBody){
   request({
        url: config.dataDumpUrl,
        method: "POST",
        json: true, // <--Very important!!!
        body: reqBody
    }, async (error, response, body) =>{
        if (error) {
           console.log('error in data post');
        }
    })
  }
```

then I call the sendData mathod in a for loop like below:

```
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++){
  sendData(reqBody);
}
```

the 1000 request is done asynchronously in for loop. Will it be blocked by any maximum simultaneous request limit?.

Comment: Can you show us some sample code, so that the question is less abstract?

Comment: @snwflk sample code provided..